# How do I make gmusicbrowser select the USB headphones as the default output?

Tags: usb, gmusicbrowser

To be clear, I'm happy that it doesn't when my cron job alarm clock goes off and the headphones have been pushed off my head when I went to sleep streaming audio from youtube, but it is inconsistent.

How can I fix it?

Edit for clarity:  It's not a cron environment problem.  It also happens if I open an xterm and launch it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed in 16.04 at least on my box.

The catch is, pavucontrol now remembers which app has which default sound sink and which fallback sound sink.  So, I can choose to set my USB headphones as an out and the on-board as a fallback, so they get used if the headphones get disconnected (I think it's the other way around actually - USB specified as a fallback, but they kick in when plugged in), but it's app specific.